# Complex string match in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, sql-server-2008, tuples

I have a complex scenario for string matching and want input from you guys. 
I have a table Named Customers. This table contains a field CustomerName varchar.
Data in the column is prefixed with Mr. Mrs. Ms.
Data could be

1. Mr. John Brady
2. Ms. Abraham Lenin
3. Mrs. John Brady
4. Mr. Michael King
5. Mrs. Neil Thomas
6. Mrs. Micheal King

Now I need to design a search query that returns me rows of only Couples and in a sequenced manner.

Like Select CustomerName from Customer where ...?? 
Result needs to be like

1. Mr. John Brady
2. Mrs. John Brady
3. Mr. Michael King
4. Mrs. Micheal King

Any Idea ?

Thanks in advance for the consideration.

Comment: What SQL queries have you tried so far?

Comment: So far no single query. Although it can be done using an SP, and doing multiple queries, and string parsing, but thats going to be too expensive for large set of data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
declare @T table(Name varchar(25))

insert into @T values
    ('Mr. John Brady'),
    ('Ms. Abraham Lenin'),
    ('Mrs. John Brady'),
    ('Mr. Michael King'),
    ('Mrs. Neil Thomas'),
    ('Mrs. Michael King')

;with C as
(
  select Name, 
         count(*) over(partition by stuff(Name, 1, charindex(' ', Name), '')) as Cnt
  from @T
)    
select Name
from C
where Cnt = 2
```

Comment: Thanks Randy and Mikael, both of you suggested a nice solution and also allowed me to learn a step further on writing queries. Looking above the solution proposed by Mikael is pretty concise and suites me more in my scenario. So I am moving ahead and mark it as an Answer. Thanks both of you gurus for helping me sort out this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you really trust your data, here is the solution:

```
--proof of concept preparation start

declare @YourTable table (name varchar(50))

insert into @YourTable (name) values
('Mr. John Brady'),
('Ms. Abraham Lenin'),
('Mrs. John Brady'),
('Mr. Michael King'),
('Mrs. Neil Thomas'),
('Mrs. Michael King')

--proof of concept preparation end

;with purenames as (
    select name, 
           LEFT(name, CHARINDEX(' ', name, 0)) salutation,
           RIGHT(name, LEN(name) - CHARINDEX(' ', name, 0)) purename
    from @YourTable
)

select p1.name
from purenames p1
inner join purenames p2 
on p1.purename = p2.purename and p1.salutation <> p2.salutation
order by p1.purename, p1.name
```

However, this will only work perfectly if the first word of the name is ALWAYS the salutation (remember, you have to trust your data).

And, of course, I had to fix `Mrs. Micheal King` to `Mrs. Michael King`, thus the pure name (no salutation) has to be identical.

Did I mention something about trusting your data? Well, the bad news is that, by experience, you cannot trust the data. However, if you have good data, you should be able to identify a good amount of the couples.

Comment: +1 for the multiple references to Trusting the Data, eg. Don't trust it!

Answer (score 0):

i doubt this is a real life solution... but you first need to normalize your strings. (in the traditional RDBMS sense, and/or in a string sense)

I'm not so sure your real data is this clean, but you could look for the first '. ' character sequence, use the remaining substring, then check for equality based on that.

use order by on the original string for the collation.

Comment: Thats what eventually im going to do, but only after i know there isnt any better way to achieve it.

Answer (score -1):

```
  WITH pattern_cnt 
     AS (SELECT string_pattern, 
                Count(string_pattern) AS CNT 
         FROM   (SELECT Substr(NAME, Instr(NAME, '.') + 1) AS STRING_PATTERN 
                 FROM   couples) 
         GROUP  BY string_pattern), 
     string_match 
     AS (SELECT NAME, 
                Substr(NAME, Instr(NAME, '.') + 1) AS PATTERN 
         FROM   couples) 
SELECT a.NAME 
FROM   pattern_cnt b, 
       string_match a 
WHERE  a.pattern = b.string_pattern 
       AND b.cnt > 1;
```